# Excel function array formula based on sumif to find minimum count

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement

I have some data where I want to find the minimum number of days it takes to reach a total sum based on some criteria.

Essentially the data is like this:

```
Date        Season  Recieval
1/01/2006   2006    500
2/01/2006   2006    100
3/01/2006   2006    150
…       
10/12/2009  2009    300
```

etc

Want I want to do is find a formula that finds the minimum number of days it takes to reach a receivals total for the season.

The formula below is what I have tried so far with no avail.

```
 =MIN(COUNT(IF(SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"2006")>2000,DATA!A:A)))
```

It doesn't matter what point it starts from, but it must take the minimum number of days to reach the 2000.

Output should be a number eg 39 (39 days consecutive to sum up to receivals of 2000).

Essentially what I want to generate is the minimum number of consecutive days required to reach the total of 2000, regardless of the starting point.

Cheers!

Comment: Please add the input and desired output in the form of excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Dates are in the range A2:A25 and Recieval in C2:C25, then try this...

```
=INDEX(A2:A25,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(SUBTOTAL(9,(OFFSET(C$2:C25,,,ROW(INDIRECT("1:25")),1)))>=2000,),0))-A2
```

The formula will get you the no. of days to reach total 2000 receival in column C.

Or if you just need to count the consecutive dates, please try..

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(SUBTOTAL(9,(OFFSET(C$2:C25,,,ROW(INDIRECT("1:25")),1)))>=2000,),0)
```

Remember both the formulas are **Array Formulas** which require a special key stroke **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** instead of Enter alone.

Comment: Will that start from the first date? or give me the minimum number of days to reach the total? ie starting from C2 you might reach 2000 in 10 days but starting at C5 you might get there in only 6.

Comment: The formula starts looking at the first date in A2, finds the date when the receival reaches 2000 and then subtract the starting date from the date found to get you the no. of days to reach 2000.

Comment: Hmmm... Good formula. But I want to find the minimum number of days in the range to reach 2000. Starting from any date, but dates must be consecutive.

Comment: When you say from any date, do you mean you have a date criteria in a cell? If so, what's the date criteria cell then?]

Comment: No specific date, just the receivals need to add up to 2000, but it can be any period of time. Eg it could start from cell c2 or c5 or c10 to when ever they sum to 2000.

Eg what is the minimum count of cells that add up to 2000?

Comment: Doesn't that mean that somehow you are required to tell the formula that start counting from this particular date say 03/01/2006 though the first date in the data set is 1/1/2006? OR all you want to know how to adjust the ranges in the formula if the data doesn't start from row2?

Comment: I don't want to specify a starting date, only that the sum of that dynamic range is equal to 2000 and what is the minimum count of consecutive dates to do that. 

Above is the formula I tried, but simply won't work.

Comment: Just added another formula, see if that does what you are trying to achieve. Also remember to confirm the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter as both the formulas are Array Formulas.

Comment: Mate, you have cracked it. What a legend.